# Combine variable and regular expression in pattern match

Tags: awk

I am looking to search a file for a column that is 3 letters followed by any 3 or 4 numerals. eg.

```
if ( $1 ~ /^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)
```

However I need the 3 letters to be a variable, so I am looking for the result of

```
SP="ABC" 
if ( $1 ~ /^/SP/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/)>
```

However, this does not work. How do I combine a variable and regular expression in the search pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SP="ABC" 
if ( $1 ~ "^" SP "[0-9]{3}")
```

You can concatenate *strings* but not `/xxx/`s which are in effect more like regular expression matching operators, and with parsing rules that can get confusing (and vary between implementations)

```
$1 ~ /ABC/ /BCD/
```

could be seen as the concatenation of `$1` matched against the concatenation of `/ABC/` (1 or 0 depending on whether `$0` matches `/ABC/`) and `/BCD/` (1 or 0 depending on whether `$0` matches `/BCD/`), or `$1` matched against `/ABC/` (0 or 1) concatenated with `$0` matched against `/BCD/` which would be confusing enough except that the `/regexp/` operator doesn't work well when combined with some others like the concatenation operator here, as there's a possible confusion with the `/` division operator.

But with parenthesis, you can get interesting (read *buggy*) behaviours:

```
$ echo 11 ab | gawk '{print $1 ~ /a/ (/b/)}'
1
$ echo 11 ab | bwk-awk '{print $1 ~ /a/ (/b/)}'
01
$ echo b | bwk-awk '{print /a/ - (/b/)}'
0-1
```

(that latter one being the result of `/a/` (0) concatenated with the result of `- (/b/)`).

---

note that in `$1 =~ "^" SP "[0-9]{3}"`, SP's content is still treated as a regexp (if it's `...`, that matches 3 characters, not 3 dots); if that's not wanted:

```
if (index($1, SP) == 1 && substr($1, length(SP)+1) ~ /^[0-9]{3}/)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Looks like I had the right idea, just needed quotes instead of slashes.  Thank you muchly.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell awk to read regular expression starting with exact chars, and then with a charater "type" in square brackets, followed by repetition number in curly brackets. Like so:

```
echo "ABC956" |  awk '{ if( $1 ~ /^ABC[0-9]{3}/) print "HELLOWORLD" }'                                 
HELLOWORLD
```

You could use logical operator `&&` to test for presence of both variable and the regular expression as well

```
echo "ABC956" |  awk -v VAR="ABC" '{ if( $1 ~ VAR && $1 ~ /[0-9]{3}/) print "HELLOWORLD" }'            
HELLOWORLD
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried this option, but ran into a problem where the data was abcde123, which this captures, but I don't want.

Comment: @Carlos so you want the pattern matching to be case insensitive ?

Comment: no, all text in this particular file is upper case.  My example of abcde123 was just relative to the extra "de" between abc and 123.